# Python Fibonacci Generator

Tags: python, fibonacci, naming-conventions

I need to make a program that asks for the amount of Fibonacci numbers printed and then prints them like 0, 1, 1, 2... but I can't get it to work. My code looks the following:

```
a = int(raw_input('Give amount: '))

def fib():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while 1:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

a = fib()
a.next()
0
for i in range(a):
    print a.next(),
```

Comment: I think 'while True' is more concise

Comment: How could the 2nd iteration understand "a=1"? Shouldn't we have to write a = a+b rather than "a, b=b, a+b"

Comment: @user177196 That expression is a two-part expression. First, it makes a tuple with `(b,a+b)` using the current values of `a` and `b`, then it unpacks that tuple when assigning it to `a,b`. (Technically speaking Python can do some optimization, but I'm ignoring this for now).

Answer (score 54):

I would use this method:

**Python 2**

```
a = int(raw_input('Give amount: '))

def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in xrange(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

print list(fib(a))
```

**Python 3**

```
a = int(input('Give amount: '))

def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

print(list(fib(a)))
```

Comment: `fib(0)` doesn't yield anything, which can be fixed using `range(n+1)` instead.

Comment: I rewrote this by using a=0, b=1, a=b and b=a+b because I was uncomfortable with that notation but it gave completely different answers. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 27):

You are giving `a` too many meanings:

```
a = int(raw_input('Give amount: '))
```

vs.

```
a = fib()
```

You won't run into the problem (as often) if you give your variables more descriptive names (3 different uses of the name `a` in 10 lines of code!):

```
amount = int(raw_input('Give amount: '))
```

and change `range(a)` to `range(amount)`.

Answer (score 17):

Since you are writing a generator, why not use two yields, to save doing the extra shuffle?

```
import itertools as it

num_iterations = int(raw_input('How many? '))
def fib():
    a,b = 0,1
    while True:
        yield a
        b = a+b
        yield b
        a = a+b

for x in it.islice(fib(), num_iterations):
    print x
```

.....

Answer (score 14):

Really simple with generator:

```
def fin(n):
    a, b = 0, 1

    for i in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b


ln = int(input('How long? '))
print(list(fin(ln))) # [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, ...]
```

Comment: So this is how `yield` works! BTW, it should be `yield b` instead of `yield a` as it repeats the elements twice (`a` becomes `b`).

Answer (score 5):

Python is a dynamically typed language. the type of a variable is determined at runtime and it can vary as the execution is in progress.
Here at first, you have declared a to hold an integer type and later you have assigned a function to it and so its type now became a function.

you are trying to apply '**a**' as an argument to **range()** function which expects an int arg but you have in effect provided a function variable as argument.

the corrected code should be

```
 a = int(raw_input('Give amount: '))

def fib():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while 1:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

b = fib()
b.next()

for i in range(a):
    print b.next(),
```

this will work

Comment: I am gettting error on this                                                                                                   
  File "D:\Projects\Python\fibonacci.py", line 18, in <module>
    b.next()

AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: I found it for Python 3, it is b.__next__(). Sorry :) and Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
def fibonacci(n):
    fn = [0, 1,]
    for i in range(2, n):
        fn.append(fn[i-1] + fn[i-2])
    return fn
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the fibonacci numbers till any number (100 in this case) with generator, you can do this.

```
def getFibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1

    while True:
        yield b
        b = a + b
        a = b - a

for num in getFibonacci():
    if num > 100:
        break
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def genFibanocciSeries():

    a=0
    b=1
    for x in range(1,10):
        yield a
        a,b = b, a+b

for fib_series in genFibanocciSeries():
    print(fib_series)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `a` is a global name so-to-say.

```
a = int(raw_input('Give amount: '))
```

Whenever Python sees an `a`, it thinks you are talking about the above one. Calling it something else (elsewhere or here) should help.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use enumerate infinite generator:

```
for i,f  in enumerate(fib()):
    print i, f
    if i>=n: break
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try the closed form solution (no guarantees for very large values of n due to rounding/overflow errors):

```
root5 = pow(5, 0.5)
ratio = (1 + root5)/2

def fib(n):
    return int((pow(ratio, n) - pow(1 - ratio, n))/root5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You had the right idea and a very elegant solution, all you need to do fix is your swapping and adding statement of a and b. Your yield statement should go after your swap as well

`a, b = b, a + b ####` should be `a,b = a+b,a #####`

```
`###yield a`
```

Answer (score 2):

## Simple way to print Fibonacci series till n number

```
def Fib(n):
    i=a=0
    b=1
    while i<n:
        print (a)
        i=i+1
        c=a+b
        a=b
        b=c




Fib(input("Please Enter the number to get fibonacci series of the Number :  "))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 3 #raw_input

def fib_gen():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while 1:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

fs = fib_gen()
next(fs)
for i in range(a):
    print (next(fs))
```

Comment: only code answers are discouraged here. It is encouraged to add some details to how this code will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've build this a while ago:

```
a = int(raw_input('Give amount: '))

fab = [0, 1, 1]
def fab_gen():
    while True:
        fab.append(fab[-1] + fab[-2])
        yield fab[-4]

fg = fab_gen()
for i in range(a): print(fg.next())
```

No that `fab` will grow over time, so it isn't a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the `a` twice. Try changing that to a different variable name.

The following seems to be working great for me.

```
def fib():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a+b

f = fib()
for x in range(100):
    print(f.next())
```

Answer (score 1):

i like this version:

```
array = [0,1]

for i in range(20):
   x = array[0]+array[1]   
   print(x)
   array[0] = array[1]
   array[1] = x
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are two solution for fiboncci generation:

```
def fib_generator(num):
    '''
    this will works as generator function and take yield into account.
    '''
    assert num > 0
    a, b = 1, 1
    while num > 0:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a+b
        num -= 1


times = int(input('Enter the number for fib generaton: '))
fib_gen = fib_generator(times)
while(times > 0):
    print(next(fib_gen))
    times = times - 1


def fib_series(num):
    '''
    it collects entires series and then print it.
    '''
    assert num > 0
    series = []
    a, b = 1, 1
    while num > 0:
        series.append(a)
        a, b = b, a+b
        num -= 1
    print(series)


times = int(input('Enter the number for fib generaton: '))
fib_series(times)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you go for complex here is one of my snippet to work on!!

```
n = int(input('Enter your number..: '))
a = 0
b = 1
c = 0
print(a)
print(b)
for i in range(3, n+1):
    c = a+b
    print(c)
    a,b=b,c
```

check out my git - rohith-sreedharan

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered this type of construct (many thanks to @KellyBundy for this), so I couldn't resist:

```
n = 20
fib = (a for a,b in [(0,1)] for _ in range(n) for a,b in [(b,a+b)])

print(list(fib))
# [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765]
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use it in a short way without through 'yield and 'next' statements

```
def fib(n):
    return n if n <= 1 else fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

Comment: Yeah but the question is asking to print the first `n` numbers, not the `n`th number...