# How to get nth result from simple function in python?

Tags: python, fibonacci

I apologize for the simplicity of this question, I have searched multiple times but it may be so simple it hasn't been asked before.

I wrote a Fibonacci function that prints every Fibonacci number under 3000.

```
def fibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < 3000:
        a, b = b, a + b
        print a
    return a
```

How can I make it so it returns the first n Fibonacci numbers?

Also, how can I make it just print the nth value? For example print [6], which would return 8.
I tried to make it a string:

```
a = str(fibonacci())
print a[6]
```

but that didn't work, and I'm not sure why. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Print prints the intermediate results to standard output, but otherwise they are lost. You'll have to store them somewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Fibonacci Generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953749/python-fibonacci-generator)

Comment: You can use `yield` in a method to turn the results into a iterable generator

Comment: That makes sense, but I am such a novice I'm not sure how I'd go about doing that. How do you store all the intermediate results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this; here's a semi-clever one:

First, change `print` to `yield`, so the function returns the numbers instead of printing them:

```
def ifibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < 3000:
        a, b = b, a + b
        yield a
```

Then use `itertools.islice` to slice out the numbers you want:

```
import itertools

print list(itertools.islice(ifibonacci(), 10))
# prints [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]

print list(itertools.islice(ifibonacci(), 6, 6+1))
# prints [13] which isn't quite right; see below
```

Note that your function doesn't output [the initial 0](http://oeis.org/A000045), so the indexes are off by one.  To fix that, move the `yield` up one line:

```
def ifibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < 3000:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

print list(itertools.islice(ifibonacci(), 6, 6+1))
# prints [8]
```

(also, this still won't print numbers larger than 3000.  fixing that is left as an exercise)

Answer (score 0):

First, your function needs to know what `n` to use. That's simple enough - just tell it `n` as an argument:

```
def fibonacci(n):
```

If you want to return the first `n` fibonacci numbers, you'll need to keep a [list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) of them:

```
    numbers = [0, 1] # Start off with the first 2 numbers
```

Then, compute the fibonacci numbers pretty much the way you did before, except stopping at the `n`th one, and adding together the last two list elements instead of `a` and `b`:

```
    # xrange(2, n) is a sequence going from 2 to n-1
    for i in xrange(2, n):
        # Add together the last two fibonacci numbers and append the result
        # to the list
        numbers.append(numbers[-2] + numbers[-1])
```

Finally, return the list:

```
    return numbers
```

The end result:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    numbers = [0, 1]
    for i in xrange(2, n):
        numbers.append(numbers[-2] + numbers[-1])
    return numbers
```

This will return a list of the first `n` fibonnaci numbers (for `n >= 2`). You'll need to special-case `n == 0` or `n == 1` if you want to handle those values.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn your function into a generator and use it in a list comprehension. The last number in the list created is the value of nth fibonacci number (`fibonacci(n)`):

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    count = 0
    while count < n:
        a, b = b, a + b
        count += 1
        yield a

fibs = [fib for fib in fibonacci(6)]
print fibs
print 'fibonacci(6):', fibs[-1]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
fibonacci(6): 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a generator:

```
def fibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        a, b = b, a + b
        yield a
```

Create a wrapper to call it n times

```
def fibn(n):
    g= fibonacci()
    return [next(g) for _ in xrange(n)][-1]

>>> fibn(5)
5
>>> fibn(15)
610
```