# infinite Fibonacci generator in python with yield error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def fib_gen():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

print(next(fib_gen())) 
print(next(fib_gen())) 
print(next(fib_gen())) 
print(next(fib_gen()))

Output: 0 
        0 
        0 
        0
```

I am trying to create an infinite Fibonacci generator in python. Please help ... Where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Fibonacci Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953749/python-fibonacci-generator)

Comment: Thanks but No @insaner.. In infinite series I get this code from web everywhere.. but  it is resetting the value of a every-time it is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each call to `fib_gen()` creates a new generator that is in initial state. Try assigning the return value of `fib_gen()` to a variable and calling `next()` on that same variable.

Answer (score 5):

You first need to create a generator object:

```
def fib_gen():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b


generator = fib_gen()

print(next(generator))
print(next(generator))
print(next(generator))
print(next(generator))
```

The output is:

```
0
1
1
2
```