# How to run through all fibonacci numbers in python generator

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, fibonacci

So i have created a function which will essentially take a value as a parameter and run the fibonacci sequence. It tends to only print 1 each time i am using next. I am not sure why it is doing this. When it reached the yield keyword it returns back the value of 1.  So far my 
code is as follows :

```
def fibonacci(n):
    curr = 1
    prev = 0
    counter = 0
    while counter < n:
        yield curr
        prev, curr = curr, prev + curr
        counter += 1


print(next(fibonacci(10)))
print(next(fibonacci(10)))
print(next(fibonacci(10)))
```

Comment: Please search the net before asking the questions that have been already answered. [Python Fibonacci Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953749/python-fibonacci-generator)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Fibonacci Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953749/python-fibonacci-generator)

Comment: With each call to `fibonacci(10)` you create a new generator/iterator which begins again with 1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate object of your generator before using it, for example:

```
g = fibonacci(10)

print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
```

will return following output:

```
1
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that works for me:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    fibonacci_list = []
    curr = 1
    prev = 0
    counter = 0
    while counter < n:
        prev, curr = curr, prev + curr
        counter += 1
        fibonacci_list.append(curr)

    return fibonacci_list;


x = fibonacci(10)
print(x)
```

Tell me if it helped

SLP