# python3: Fibonacci generator not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, fibonacci

I know that the following is a suboptimal implementation of a fibonacci generator compared to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3954407/2409793), but I cannot seem to understand why it is not working as expected:

```py
def fibonacci_sequence():
    fl, fp = 1, 1
    while True:
        yield (fl + fp)
        store = fl + fp
        fp = fl
        fl = store


for i in range(10):
    print(next(fibonacci_sequence()))
```

It keeps printing 2 all the time.

Isn't the generator's state being updated underneath `yield` keyword on each iteration?

Answer (score 5):

You are instantiating a **new** generator in each loop iteration. Do instead:

```
fib = fibonacci_sequence()

for i in range(10):
    print(next(fib))  # keep calling next on the same generator object
```

To generate the entire sequence from the start, you might want to `yield fp` instead of `yield (fl + fp)`.