# Faster way to get list of numbers

Tags: python

So I have a piece of code:

```
def test(num):
    count = 1
    l = []
    while len(l) < 16:
        x = num % count
        if x >= 16 or x in l:
            pass
        else:
            l.append(x)
        
        count += 1
    
    return l
```

that takes a number `45071` for example and modulos it with `count`, which starts at 1 and goes up by one every loop cycle. Then, if `45071 % count` is less than 16, it is appended to a list unless the same value is already there. This loop stops once there are 16 numbers in the list, from 0 to 15. Here is the results of a test run:

```
>>> print(test(45071))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 4, 11, 15, 14, 13, 12, 6, 9, 10]
```

This works and all, but with bigger lists and lots of different numbers it gets quite slow. I was wondering if there is any way to make this faster, or another way to get a list of numbers from 0 to 15. The more 'random' the numbers the better. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How big is the biggest list in elements?

Comment: Wait, do you just want a list of random numbers between 0 and 15?

Comment: @Iarsks yeah only 0-15, but not completely random.

Comment: @Yash the list that is returned is put into another list that can have up to 100 values in it.

Comment: Why not just use the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module?

Comment: @Matt I don't want completely random numbers because I want to be able to generate the same list again with the same number.

Comment: It seems like a `XY` problem to me.

Comment: If speed is concern, use generators and **yield** instead.

Comment: @dmitryro Is yeild a built it function? Do I need to import anything?

Comment: yield is like return in iterative form

Comment: Yes,  Python3 has **yield** and generators are much faster.

Comment: So how would I implement it?

Comment: See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953749/python-fibonacci-generator)

Comment: Using a generator doesn't solve the basic algorithmic problem here, which is that you're chewing through an unbounded number of pseudorandom numbers when you really only want 16 of them.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As quite a few people have suggested already, use `random`.  It's not really random (nothing is) -- if you call `random.seed` with the same seed and make the same pseudo-random function calls afterwards, you'll always get the same pseudo-random results.

```
>>> import random
>>> def shuffled_ints(n, seed):
...     random.seed(seed)
...     ints = list(range(n))
...     random.shuffle(ints)
...     return ints
...
>>> shuffled_ints(16, 45071)
[0, 10, 12, 14, 8, 1, 15, 2, 13, 7, 6, 5, 3, 9, 11, 4]
>>> shuffled_ints(16, 1234)
[3, 2, 6, 4, 7, 10, 8, 5, 11, 12, 13, 9, 15, 0, 1, 14]
>>> shuffled_ints(16, 45071)
[0, 10, 12, 14, 8, 1, 15, 2, 13, 7, 6, 5, 3, 9, 11, 4]
```

Using `shuffle` (or an equivalent) is more efficient than your original method because you don't need to keep generating random numbers and throwing them out.

A slightly more concise version might be to use `random.sample`:

```
def shuffled_ints(n, seed):
    random.seed(seed)
    return random.sample(range(n), n)
```

Comment: What does the `seed` do?

Comment: It does the exact thing your question is asking for. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#notes-on-reproducibility

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for random numbers then you can use a library with this functionality. For example [random.randrange()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)  or [numpy.random.rand()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html)

Comment: Again, I don't want a list of completely random numbers.